# Lebesgue integral and monotonicity of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Could you please help me to understand the following concept about the Lebesgue integral from Strichartz's "The way of analysis":

> The point is that without monotonicity, or at least some such
>   restriction, there need be no relationship between the integral of $f$ and the limit of the integrals of $f_n$, where $f_n$ are simple functions such that $\lim f_n(x)=f(x)$ pointwise.

Comment: I don't have the book, but presumably he's just given an example in which $f_n \to f$ pointwise, but $\int f_n \not\to \int f$.

Comment: Hint: $f_n = 1_{[0, n]} / n$

Comment: Hint2: $f_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}$